# How can the Raspberry Pi emulate a USB storage device?

Tags: usb, file-server

USB storage devices, such as USB sticks and harddrives, are common to attach external  storage to any kind of computer. How can the Raspberry Pi emulate an USB storage? The easiest application was to directly access the SD card via USB, but one could also provide acccess to files via Ethernet. I thought about the following layout for an "*USB cloud stick*":

```
Computer <---USB---> |Raspberry Pi| <---Ethernet---> Cloud, NAS etc.
```

The computer should only see a normal USB stick to read and write files from. The Raspberry Pi would act as programmable bridge that map directory listings and file accesss to request to a cloud storage. You could access cloud storage hosters with any computer (including black box media players) *via USB without having to install any additional software* on the computer. The Raspberry Pi USB bridge should also be able to encrypt/decrypt files on the fly, so one could store files encrypted in the cloud and access them on any device like a normal USB drive.

**Edit:** Existing products with *similar but limited* functionality include [Wireless Media Stick](http://hsti.com/wirelessmediastick/overview) and [USB-over-Network](http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network.html). Access to files in the cloud may be possible by mounting virtual storage with [cloud drive](http://www.clouddrive.com.au/) or similar software and encryption with TrueCrypt or EncFS - passwords would be stored on the SD card of Raspberry Pi only but one could access the storage with any computer without having to type in a passphrase on a untrusted machine.

Comment: So all you want is a method of sharing files between the Pi and Computer?

Comment: I think what he wants is to have a partition or shared folder on his Pi that is mountable via USB on other machines. The idea being that you could plug the raspi into any computer and that folder/partion acts like a flash drive and can be written to without any additional software.

Comment: The Pi should only act as gateway between *any* computer, including black boxes, and for instance Amazon cloud. The gateway could also encrypt the files on the fly.

Comment: We really need an FTDI expansion board!

Comment: Scrap that - [this](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/RPi.htm) would be perfect!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain If the TTL-232R-RPi debug cable is designed for debugging it would need a custom driver to be used for emulating a USB device. The RPi Hub Module sold by FTDI seems to be designed to connect USB devices to the RPi, no the other way round.

Comment: They are selling it as a debug cable, but it is just an FTDI chip. Not sure whether you can persuade it to emulate a storage device tbh.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain - no, you cannot.  USB Mass Storage devices have a particular protocol which is supported by the host operating system.  You can of course create a driver to make something else look like a sort of storage device to a particular operating system, but it would not be a "USB Mass Storage" device but rather a "custom storage device connected via USB"

Comment: This is a very strange thing to do? I cannot understand why you want to plug the Pi as an SD card to the computer and then share the Pi's share to LAN/WAN. Your obsession on the USB is blocking your view of other solutions. It seems a bit weird. Just share a folder over LAN and map the drive in your PC while the cloud thing carries on. Why involve a USB cable? Many media players need to be plugged into the LAN - which you map your Pi over lan and it will also get all the files, just like any other PC that maps the network resource. Why do you need the USB cable?

Comment: @ppumkin: Because "mapping the drive in" or "plugging into the LAN" requires to configure the PC (or media player). Just plugging into an USB port does not require any administration and one does not need to expose any passwords to the PC. Note that I want to share storage from a cloud drive, which *always* requires passwords or even installation of client software.

Comment: Oh- You want to share your CLOUDS files to your media player via USB emulation. I see the point now. Your question confused me a bit. Very interesting concept though.

Comment: [Looks interesting ...](http://www.armadeus.com/wiki/index.php?title=USB_Gadget)

Comment: If the USB chip on the Pi supports swithcing between HOST / SLAVE then you got a chance. I cannot find any data on this. Otherwise you can forget about it- No software can emulate this because of hardware controlled negotiation.  Was thinking maybe using an addon USB chip that supports this.. But how will you proxy data to it? Over UART?VERY slow! bitbanged USB? even slower! Many dev kits use this kind of USB controller to allow testing of addon devices. Some hard drives use a SATA -> USB chip. That could help solve the problem- Maybe the Pi can store data via USB too while media reads it??

Answer (score 16):

EDIT: This answer only applies to older Raspberry Pi devices.  The Raspberry Pi 4 (and the Pi Zero) support USB Gadget Mode which allows what the OP is asking for.  The rest of this post only applies to Raspberry Pi 1, 2 and 3 which do not have hardware support for USB Gadget Mode.

---

The problem is that the Pi's USB connection to the PC doesn't have the data pins connected - only the power pins.  So you can't use this to speak USB because it's not wired up.

Your only option with the Pi would be to 'bit bang' USB using the GPIO pins, but this is very slow and potentially unreliable.  I suspect you would only really be able to emulate a keyboard or mouse - anything higher bandwidth would probably be too much for the CPU to cope with, given the tight timing requirements of bit banging something like USB.

Another alternative would be to find a device that lets you connect two computers together via USB, to make a kind of network.  But then you may as well just use the Ethernet connection...

Comment: I've previously played with a GP32 which can behave like a host even when plugged in a hub as a client.  If the Raspberry can behave like a host on the USB-ports (not the power one) then a similar trick should be possible there too.  Perhaps USB-to-go can do it?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Definitely worth investigating, although per the below answer it may prevent the Ethernet from working, if you mean to switch the hardware port to OTG.  Unless OTG supports a hub with the downstream ports going both ways?

Comment: I don't know. Hopefully somebody will just try and see what happens

Comment: Huh? You are mistaken by the micro usb port used for the power adapter. What about the 2 proper USB ports? With some emulation software it would be possible to plug that usb into a PC and emulate Storage - eg - Android phone when you plug in usb. - But there is not reason for that because you plug the Pi into your network, share your "cloud" folder via samba or whatever(wifi or lan)- and also at the same time do your cloud synching whatever it is you want to do. LAN can handle many request on various ports

Comment: @ppumkin: Why am I mistaken by the micro USB port?  The data pins aren't connected, so you can't send data across it.  The downstream "proper" USB ports are 'host' ports, so it is not possible to plug them into a PC without some kind of converter device in the middle.  Software emulation is not enough, because of the way the USB protocol works.  You might be thinking of Ethernet where you can plug any two devices together, but USB doesn't work like this.  If you don't believe me, have a read of the USB specification, especially the parts about USB hosts vs peripherals.

Comment: @Malvineous Sorry? But that is what I meant. What you said. The micro USB is obvious that is power only . The OP was talking about the actual full sized USB ports. UNless the on board CHIP supports host/salve switching then yes- Like I said in the main comments. It won't work. Have to think of something clever. and the GPIO is going to be extremely slow.

Comment: @ppumkin: Oh right, you replied to my post so I thought you were talking about something I said, not what the OP said!

Comment: Just wanted to add that "Bit-banging" USB is not an option. USB is a long, long way from something like I2C which can be bit-banged.   Possibly the most practical approach is to use one of those AVR micros that has a USB device port built into it, and then communicate to it via the serial port on the Pi.  (e.g. https://www.olimex.com/Products/AVR/Proto/AVR-USB-162/ )

Comment: @greggo: Do you mean bit-banging USB is not an option generally or just on the Pi?  A quick Google search reveals many projects that successfully bit bang USB 1.1.

Comment: @Malvineous At 12 MHz or just 1.5 ? Clock period is [83.33+/-0.2 us] for 12 Mhz, and [666.6+/-10 us] for 1.5 MHz. Bear in mind you need to recover the clock on receive, which presumably means sampling at least 5 - 10 times the clock rate. Do these implementations allow interrupts while talking to USB devices?

Comment: @Malvineous, ok, looked at one. It seems to be 1.5 Mhz (not sure), was done in asm, on a machine with completely predictable instruction execution times, so to qualify, "not on the Pi, probably not in anything that isn't going to be basically dedicated to the USB implementation" (until I get corrected again :-)   Also, many google hits I got refer to bit-banging something slower *through* USB via a FT232 chip or similar. In any case, a big difference between 'possible' and 'practical' here, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 9):

Based on a quick perusal of the BCM2835 data sheet (http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) chapter 15, it looks like USB OTG is supported in HW, so theoretically, it might just be a matter of SW to support the proposed scheme.  I'm not a USB protocol expert (or even novice, really), but it would be pretty cool to have this functionality.

Looking at a description of the BeagleBone (http://elinux.org/BeagleBone), it appears to support something similar, although there is specific mention of a connector that supports this mode.  It would be unfortunate if the Raspberry Pi is limited due only to connector selection.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Even if the SOC supports it, the LAN9512 hub device on a model B probably gets in the way of running the USB port "backwards" in device mode.  On a model A (or if you remove that and install R37 & R38) you could get the SOCs USB port to the external jack - but then you would not have ethernet, and would only have the sdcard for potential storage.

Answer (score 8):

This now seems to be possible using a PiZero - see https://web.archive.org/web/20210120154409/http://pi.gbaman.info/?p=699 for more.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Case in point: this link no longer exists.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately though this seems simple, as best as I can tell, it hasn't been done. See this thread and very detailed answer for more details

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/serve-files-over-usb

And a **Pi specific answer** here: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=4938

Comment: Thanks for the links. Looks like [this device](http://hsti.com/wirelessmediastick/overview) may do part of what I want, but its proprietary and only works in one direction (virtual read-only USB storage).

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't particularly concerned about performance, you could probably get a USB capable microcontroller with USB mass storage code (you could for example reprogram the STM32F103 debug interface on a $10 STM32F0 discovery eval module), carefully connect that to the pi's serial port as a back end, and run at several hundred kilobaud.

Better performance would likely be had by interfacing to the client PC via ethernet, but that would require a custom driver or different presentation to the host operating system - ie, you'd be a network attached storage device or share server.

Off the shelf file transfer cables were I believe already mentioned, but that would require appropriate software for the client PC and source-level linux driver support for the pi end.

Comment: Yup. See also https://www.olimex.com/Products/AVR/Proto/AVR-USB-162/

Answer (score 4):

I found out that Arduino can emulate a USB device, the [Arduino Leonardo](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLeonardo) even out of the box. The [LUFA USB stack](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php) can be used on Arduino and it implements a USB mass storage device driver (see [this tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Music-Playing-Alarm-Clock/step6/USB-Mass-Storage-with-MicroSD/)). This setup could be used to map [USB to SCSI commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI) such as understood by the SD card reader. I don't know enough about SCSI but it looks like the SD card on Raspberry Pi and the USB-via-Arduino could be used together on the same bus. Sure this idea is not a full solution...

Comment: -1 Since the topic is about the Raspberry Pi and not Arduino.

Comment: I know, this answer is no full solution! I hope that that questions about Raspberry Pi as a tool instead of an an end in itself are on-topic and broadening the view to related project helps. In this case I found [this tutorial](http://elasticsheep.com/2010/04/teensy2-usb-mass-storage-with-an-sd-card/) how to use an SD card as USB mass storage device. Maybe one could use an Arduino or another ATMEGA32U4 to get USB to the SIP bus which is also available on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: No, you can't really share access to the sdcard, other than by electrical switching.  Only one host can "mount" a given filesystem at a time (for the types of filesystems used on cards - network filesystems are different in this respect).

Answer (score 4):

The Pi Zero and Pi Zero W are now available and support the Gadget interface ([Kernal.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/gadget/intro.html), [linux-sunxi.org](https://linux-sunxi.org/USB_Gadget)) allowing several different profiles, including USB Mass Storage and virtual networking.

The closest solution to the OP's request is to use a networking protocol between the Pi and the host PC, and then some other form of networking protocol from the Pi to the cloud/network provider.  The Pi Zero W has builtin Wi-Fi, so could even connect directly to the cloud/network provider.  Networking both of those links will be the easiest way to get the job done.  There are many networking protocols and cloud providers available.

Trying to use USB Mass Storage would be a bad idea; you would have to write or rewrite a driver-level adaptation between USB Mass Storage and the Pi.  You'd either start with [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol), or wind up with something similar.  MTP has severe performance issues ([Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3ff1rm/why_does_everything_use_mtp_these_days_mtp_sucks/), [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/mtp-sucks-usb-ms-t2372390/page2), [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2811kx/mtp_is_such_a_bad_way_of_transferring_files_that/)) so I suggest the networking approach.

There should be lots of programs and projects in that direction.  From the Pi's perspective, it's just acting like a fileserver/sync server, so any similar tutorial should get you started.  Looking into things like Pi-based [Seafile](https://www.seafile.com/), [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/), [SugarSync](https://www.sugarsync.com/), and [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/) servers should get you started.

A few useful guides on the Pi Zero as a USB Gadget:

- [Raspberry PI Zero Dongle With Power Switch](http://sdatic.com/raspberry-pi-zero-dongle-with-power-switch/)
- [Raspberry Pi Zero as Multiple USB Gadgets](http://irq5.io/2016/12/22/raspberry-pi-zero-as-multiple-usb-gadgets/)
- [Raspberry Pi Zero USB Dongle](https://www.novaspirit.com/2016/10/18/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-dongle/)
- [Giving The Pi Zero USB, Ethernet, And Serial Over USB](https://hackaday.com/2016/02/25/giving-the-pi-zero-usb-ethernet-and-serial-over-usb/)
- [Turning your Raspberry PI Zero into a USB Gadget](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/overview)
- [Raspberry Pi Zero OTG Mode](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41)
- [Raspberry Pi Zero – Programming over USB! (Part 1)](http://blog.gbaman.info/?p=699)

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to how USB works, you see whenever two things are connected with USB there is all ways a USB host and a USB device and never the twain shall switch places.  A USB host does all kinds of things that USB devices cannot do mostly to sync up data transfer between all devices connected to the USB bus.  Check out the [USB wikipedia page for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Communication).

What you're talking about doing is forcing two USB hosts (the Raspberry Pi and a computer) to communicate which unfortunately is simply not supported by the USB standard.  There are some devices which can fake a data transfer between two USB hosts but as Malvineous mentioned you'd be better off using ethernet.

Your question specifically mentions using the Raspberry Pi to emulate *USB storage* but have you considered setting up the Raspberry Pi as a NAS?  Using the Raspberry Pi as a NAS box basically does exactly what you asked for but instead of using USB it would be using your network.  [Here are great instructions](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_NAS) on how to do this if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. So my questions is about *how to implement a USB device* using a Raspberry Pi. A NAS, however is not an answer to this question.

Comment: If you want the Raspberry Pi to have the ability to be a USB device I suggest you investigate the products at http://www.ftdichip.com/ more than likely you'll be able to wire up a board that uses the Pi's GPIO pins to interface with an FTDI chip and that will give you USB device capability.  You'll probably also need to write a driver to communicate with the FTDI device.

Comment: Except that "the twain shall switch places" if they are  USB OTG devices...

Answer (score 2):

I can do it with my old Nokia N900 Phone using the usb gadget driver included with the stock Nokia kernel.
The emulated device behaves exactly like a real one, you can even boot a PC from it.

Comment: Could you provide some details? You don't talk about just providing the storage at your phone via USB like most other smartphones can do, do you? As far as I understand, a USB gadget driver only provides a [mapping from SCSI to USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI), so one would still need to map SCSI to some cloud storage API.

Answer (score 1):

The USB standard are host based.  That means that one device has to controll all communication with the connected devices.  Clients can be a simple device or a hub.  The hub is a host proxy for the clients connected to the hub, and communicates with the host (or hub) it's connected to.

As the original design of USB looks, you can't connect two hosts together (your PC and the RPi).

There are extentions though, *USB On-The-Go*, which allow a USB connection to see if it is connected to a host or a client, and adjust it's role depending on that.  To this to work, you have to have support in the hardware. I don't belive the RPi is designed to do that.

For more information, look att http://www.usb.org/home or even http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus

In short, I don't belive that it can be done.

Comment: Another answer contradicts your lack of OTG support remark.

Comment: @Alex, look at the date stamps.  Anders posted this in 2012, before the Pi Zero or A+ were available.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser , look at the date stamps. I posted my response the day after Anders wrote his comment.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain and in 2012, there was not support for that for Raspberry and Rasbperian (or any other software I know of).  So yes, in THAT time frame, I was right. The RPi Zero came many years later...

Now we have support for it for RPi Zero, which is mentioned in another post, as you wrote.